# Is reading from Python zipfile thread-safe?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-zipfile

I have seen several differing opinions on this.

I don't see anything in the [latest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) (3.9.2).

Can I read multiple different entries in a ZipFile safely?

I have seen some unusual errors like "Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths," and I am wondering if they are because I'm reading entries in parallel.

EDIT: Please don't close it as duplicate of [Is python zipfile thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195206/is-python-zipfile-thread-safe) . If you read only the title, you'd think it's a duplicate. But if you read the actual question, it asks about *writing* zip files (even though writing zip files is inherently not really parallelizable). This question asks about *reading* zip files.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, at least it's planned to be thread-safe: actual data I/O goes through a [`_SharedFile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28ad12f8fe889a741661eb99daacebd9243cc1ba/Lib/zipfile.py#L716) object, which uses the [`ZipFile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28ad12f8fe889a741661eb99daacebd9243cc1ba/Lib/zipfile.py#L1181)-level [lock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28ad12f8fe889a741661eb99daacebd9243cc1ba/Lib/zipfile.py#L1252) for reading, maintaining a private position for itself:

```
def read(self, n=-1):
    with self._lock:
        if self._writing():
            raise ValueError("Can't read from the ZIP file while there "
                    "is an open writing handle on it. "
                    "Close the writing handle before trying to read.")
        self._file.seek(self._pos)
        data = self._file.read(n)
        self._pos = self._file.tell()
        return data
```

you can try looking at `_seekable` of the `ZipFile`, but normally it's going to be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this question, CPython's reading ZipFile was not threadsafe. https://bugs.python.org/issue42369

However, it has since been fixed and backported to 3.9 and on https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/26974